# Showing equivalence of weak convergence on closed and open intervals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

Quick question. Let $I$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. If I am given that $u_{m},u \in W^{1,\infty}(I)$ and I want to show that $u_{m} \rightharpoonup^{*} u$ in $L^{\infty}(I)$. Then I have to show that given any $\phi  \in L^{1}(I)$ I can show $$\int_{I}u_{m}\phi dx \rightarrow \int_{I}u \phi dx$$

Would it be equivalent to instead show $$\int_{\bar{I}}u_{m}\phi dx \rightarrow \int_{\bar{I}}u \phi dx$$

where the integral is taken over $\bar{I}$ and I define $u_{m}$ and $u$ on $\partial I$ using the trace operator $T: W^{1,\infty}(I) \rightarrow L^{\infty}(\partial I)$?

If the answer to the above question is yes, would it be so because $L^{\infty}(I) = L^{\infty}(\bar{I})$?

Comment: If the boundary of $I$ does not have measure $0$, then $L^\infty(I)$ is not the same as $L^\infty(\overline I)$.

Comment: @Etienne What are the necessary conditions which would allow us to state that the boundary in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ has measure zero? Would I be wrong then in saying that the two proofs are equivalent?

Comment: If your open set is "regular", say with a Lipschitz boundary, then it is OK. As for your second question, I don't know; but it seems much easier at first sight to go through the first proof. Why do you want to consider $\overline I$?

Comment: @Etienne By then it's okay do you mean that the measure of the boundary is zero? I will update the question soon to show why. But for me it doesn't seem that $ \int_{\bar{I}}u_{m}\phi dx \rightarrow \int_{\bar{I}}u \phi dx$ implies $\int_{I}u_{m}\phi dx \rightarrow \int_{I}u \phi dx$ for $\phi \in L^{1}(\bar{I})$ would necessary follow, what do you think?

Comment: Yes, "OK" means "measure $0$". And then, you can simply ignore the boundary if you integrate wrt $dx$.